# ActiveRecord, which comes first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Simple question really, in the order of processing which will happen first when saving a new item.

1. `:before_create`
2. `:validates`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`validates` goes first. From the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks):

```
(-) save
(-) valid
(1) before_validation
(-) validate
(2) after_validation
(3) before_save
(4) before_create
(-) create
(5) after_create
(6) after_save
(7) after_commit
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked the docs, great list of the order.

Answer (score 2):

`before_create` isn't called until an object is valid, so validates is called first.

Answer (score 2):

from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

```
(-) save

(-) valid

(1) before_validation

(-) validate

(2) after_validation

(3) before_save

(4) before_create

(-) create

(5) after_create

(6) after_save

(7) after_commit
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked the docs, great list of the order.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> (-) save
>
> (-) valid
>
> (1) before_validation
>
> (-) validate
>
> (2) after_validation
>
> (3) before_save
>
> (4) before_create
>
> (-) create
>
> (5) after_create
>
> (6) after_save
>
> (7) after_commit